# Deploy App to WP8.1 and Device not show up in VS2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

1. My Phone is unlocked
2. My Phone is connected to the PC and the icon shows up.
3. The 'Device' option shows up in VS2012 and I'm able to deploy.
4. The 'Device' option doesn't show up in VS2013 and I set the start project as WP8.1 project properly.

I used some of the 8.1 feature result in I must use VS2013.
But in 2013 the 'Device' option doesn't show up, I tried reboot, delete all the temp file and reset the startup project, still no device shows up.

But it was always there for the other projects in VS2012.

I'm confused....

Comment: look at the updates for the VS

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer.
2013 and 2012 are a little different.
device and emulator show up at the same panel in 2012.
But in 2013, we need to switch the SolutionPlatform to ARM,
Then we can see the device. That's pretty much of it. :-P